# Memory Exhaust while saving order data in Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, database, event-observer, sales-order, zend-framework

I add a custom attribute from my module to sales order like this:

```
$attribute  = array(
    'type'          => 'int',
    'backend_type'  => 'int',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label'         => 'Admin Id',
    'visible'       => false,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined'  => false,
    'searchable'    => true,
    'filterable'    => true,
    'comparable'    => true,
    'default'       => NULL
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'admin_id', $attribute);
$installer->addAttribute('quote', 'admin_id', $attribute);
```

and then I want to set the custom attribute data after I place an order using observer like this:

**etc/config.xml**

```
<global>
    <events> 
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vendor_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Vendor_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>orderPlace</method>
                </vendor_module>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

**Model/Observer.php**

```
class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer
{
   public function orderPlace($event)
   {
     $order = $event->getOrder();
     if($this->isAdmin()){
       $adminId = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getUserId();
       if($adminId){
         $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());

         $orderModel->addData(array('admin_id'=>$adminId));
         $orderModel->save(); 
       }
     }
     return $this;
   }

   private function isAdmin()
   {
      if(Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())
      {
          return true;
      }

      if(Mage::getDesign()->getArea() == 'adminhtml')
      {
          return true;
      }

      return false;
   }
}
```

but I always got an error like this:

> Allowed memory size of 10485760 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

or this:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/vitamin/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 298

Answer (score 0):

try to increase this values on php setting

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds
```